# How to apply default timezone only when not provided by input string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, date-parsing

I'm trying to write a function that takes a timestamp string as an input (same formats as the javascript `Date` class constructor) and returns the milliseconds since the epoch. If a timezone is not specified in the timestamp UTC should be used as the default. Basically I want the following but with a default timezone:

```
(input) => new Date(input).valueOf();
```

The main problem is the multitude of formats. There's too many possible ways to format a date for me to write a timezone parser I can be confident in. There might even be some formats I don't know about.

I tried to utilize the parser already in use in the `Date` class but if I use the constructor I can't tell whether the resulting timezone is due to it being specified in the timestamp or if it's the default.

```
new Date('2020-11-11 00:00').valueOf() === new Date('2020-11-11 00:00+02:00').valueOf(); // May be true or false depending on the local timezone
```

I tried using `moment-timezone`. It exposes a `setDefault` method but it doesn't work consistently:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'; // 0.5.27

moment.tz.setDefault('UTC');
moment('2020-11-11').valueOf(); // 1605052800000
moment('2020-11-11 UTC').valueOf(); // 1605052800000
moment('Nov 11 2020').valueOf(); // 1605045600000 <-- expected 1605052800000 instead. Likely affected by local timezone.
moment('Nov 11 2020 UTC').valueOf(); // 1605052800000
```

If only I had access to whatever parser the `Date` class uses I could discriminate based on whether a timezone is defined or not but I don't think it's exposed.

**How can I use a default timezone without overwriting possible timezone definitions in the timestamps?**

Note: I'm using node.js so there's no need to consider browser differences.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about which formats you expect to support.  If you're looking to parse *anything* that might be a date, sorry but you're out of luck.  Why? Because you could encounter something like `1/2/2020` and you'd have no idea if it represented January 2nd or February 1st.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint that's a good point. Of course we can't have everything. I meant to support the same formats the `Date` class constructor supports so `1/2/2020` would be Jan 2nd. I'll edit the question to include that assumption.

Comment: By the ECMAScript spec, the `Date` constructor supports [only one format](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format).  Anything else is implementation-specific, and varies considerably across browsers.  In particular, most browsers will use a culture-specific interpretation. 
 That means some users will see `new Date("1/2/2020")` interpreted as January 2nd, and some would see it as February 1st, and some would get an `Invalid Date` error.  In short, you can't rely on the `Date` object for parsing culture-specific formats.

Comment: Whoa, today I learned. I think that's an acceptable answer (hint). I guess I'll have to define a set of formats I support and parse those instead of chasing any generic solution.